# Is it possible to emit an arbitrary Spectral Color

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy

I've been playing with frequencies of colors lately, and just out of curiosity, was wondering if we have technology to generate a spectral color from an arbitrary frequency (to some degree of accuracy), or do we have to stumble on the right gas to heat up?

Comment: If you don't need much power, you can send the light from an incandescent lamp through a monochromator and get an arbitrary wavelength.

Comment: Related: [Does there exist a laser that is tunable over the whole visible spectrum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10566/does-there-exist-a-laser-that-is-tunable-over-the-whole-visible-spectrum)